# Is it possible to convert a struct with many items into a struct with a subset of those items?

Tags: go

I am looking for a way to convert a larger struct to another struct which contains a subset of the properties in the larger one.

Like an interface, but with properties.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foobar struct {
    foo string
    bar string
}

type Bar struct {
    bar string
}

func main() {
    foobar := Foobar{}
    bar := foobar.(Bar)
    fmt.Println(bar)
}
```

Obviously the above does not work as: `invalid operation: foobar (variable of type Foobar) is not an interface`

But subsequent attempts don't work

```
func main() {
    var foobar interface{} = Foobar{}
    bar := foobar.(*Bar)
    fmt.Println(bar)
}
```

fails with `panic: interface conversion: interface {} is main.Foobar, not main.Bar`

Comment: you might want to check https://github.com/jinzhu/copier

Answer (score 0):

Different structs are different types and can't be assigned to each other. I think for what you are trying to do you just want a nested struct.

```
type (
    Bar struct {
        bar string
    }
    Foobar struct {
        foo string
        bar Bar
    }
)

func main() {
    foobar := Foobar{bar: Bar{"bbb"}}
    bar := foobar.bar
    fmt.Println(bar.bar)
}
```

Also type assertions can only be used with interfaces.